# Why does $Failed have attribute HoldAll?

Tags: evaluation, implementation-details, attributes

Why does `$Failed` have attribute `HoldAll`?  Are there typical situations where `$Failed` is returned as a head that must not evaluate further, or is this just a relic from Mathematica's early times?

```
In[1]:= Attributes[$Failed]
Out[1]= {HoldAll, Protected}
```

Comment: It is not very common, but sometimes, `$Failed` is used as a head, like `f[x___]:= $Failed[x]`. This makes it possible to have "return code" returned, rather than just a fact of failure. Basically, when this is used, it is usually in the error-reporting fall-back rule. In some cases, one may want to not evaluate the arguments `x` (e.g. if `f` is `Hold*`). I don't use `$Failed` in such fashion myself, but I've seen such code, and I don't find any particular reason not to use it in this way. Of course, one could also use `$Failed[Hold[x]]`, but arguably this is a clumsier method.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I think you should post that as an answer. I doubt we can  get a more insightful one.

Comment: @belisarius I'd wait for a while. There are much more knowledgable folks than me, who may shed some more light on this. There might be other reasons of which I am not aware. My previous comment has a status of an educated guess backed by some evidence, rather than an authoritative answer, which is why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Ok,just bookmark it for later if nothing better comes in. We should keep out unanswered pyre low :)

Comment: @belisarius Yep, agree with your last point. Will revisit this one some time soon.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Hehe, I remember that a lot of your posts end with "I will change/improve/revisit this soon":)  That's why I agree with beli 100%. I would also recommend to post the comment as an answer. The hypothetical more knowledgable people can either post their own answer or improve your own.

Comment: @Ajasja All right, you convinced me. Once some better answer appears, I will delete mine. Also, it is CW, so people can edit it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not very common, but sometimes, `$Failed` is used as a head, like

```
f[x___]:= $Failed[x]
```

This makes it possible to have "return code" returned, rather than just a fact of failure.

Basically, when this is used, it is usually in the error-reporting fall-back rule. In some cases, one may want to not evaluate the arguments `x` (e.g. if `f` is `Hold*`). I don't use `$Failed` in such fashion myself, but I've seen such code, and I don't find any particular reason not to use it in this way. Of course, one could also use `$Failed[Hold[x]]`, but arguably this is a clumsier method.